# Direct to a specific Rabbitmq queue from celery

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have a RabbitMQ server running and I'm trying to execute a task in it.
I use celery for this and want to direct to a specific queue with specific exchange.

**celery code**

```
broker_uri='amqp://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx:5672;amqp://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx:5672;amqp://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx:5672/'
backend_uri="mongodb+srv://xxxxxx.mongodb.net/celery_test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

app = Celery('TestApp', broker=broker_uri,backend=backend_uri)

@app.task
def reverse(text):
    sleep(10)
    return text[:-1]
```

when I run this, it automatically access a queue and an exchange which I haven't defined. **How do I change this?**

execution result

```
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 3 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define queue by using kombu.

```
from kombu import Queue, Exchange
sample_queue = Queue(name='sample_queue', exchange=Exchange('sample_exchange', <set exchange type>'topic', durable=True),
                routing_key='sample')
```

To route a task to a queue set task_routes

```
task_routes = {
    'reverse': {
        'queue': 'sample_queue',
        'routing_key': 'sample',
    },
}
```

check documentation [exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#exchanges-queues-and-routing-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, queue and exchange names can be defined this way,

```
app.conf.task_default_queue='queue'
app.conf.task_default_exchange='exchange'
app.conf.task_default_routing_key='key'
```

Seems like it's not possible to specify the types of queue and exchange.